# How can I find values in a row from mytable

Tags: mysql

I have a table which have about 50,000 rows but it will increase.
The table looks like

```
site    serial     x    y
3         549     74    15
4         550     74    14
1         551     74    13
2         552     74    12
3         553     74    11
4         554     74    10
5         555     74     9
4         556     74     8
3         557     74     7
5         558     75    15
6         559     75    14
1         560     80    20
1         551     80    21
2         552     80    22
3         553     80    23
4         554     80    24
5         555     80    25
and so on
```

I'd like to select x and y where serial is sequential when site is start from 1 and ends at 5(this number is changed case by case). But I don't know where serial starts when site starts at 1(the above is just a example). For instance, in the above table, x and y are needed to be selected where serial is from 551 to 555(The first sequence).

Comment: Could you please show some effort and post the SQL queries you already tried?

Comment: What do the dots represent?

Comment: @Thomas G Sorry, I usually try queries but in this case I couldn't make any query to try. The only thing I can make is SELECT x, y WHERE.

Comment: @Strawberry They means something. I'm sorry I thought a dot could mean "blah blah". I think you still couldn't understand because I couldn't explain exactly. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from NAME_TABLE xx where xx.serial >= YOUR_VALUE and xx.serial <= YOUR_ANOTHER_VALUE order by xx.site
```

you must first specify what you want to select - all is `select *`, or if you want only x and y, then do this:

```
select x, y from NAME_TABLE
```

then if you have condition, you must specify that condition - `where xx.serial >= YOUR_VALUE`

you can combine conditions using `AND` -> `xx.serial >= YOUR_VALUE and xx.serial <= YOUR_ANOTHER_VALUE`

and if you want it to be sorted in any way, user `orderby` -> `order by xx.site`

hope that helps!

Comment: And never use `SELECT *`

Comment: sorry guys - removed reference to w3school, and added different select

Comment: @Lukas Novicky Sorry I made you confused. I should have made question that you could understand. I edited my question. Please refer to it.